# Problema de herencias en clases base

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Buen día. Tengo el siguiente repositorio base:

```
public class BaseService<T, Y> : IBaseService<T, Y> where T : BaseAttributes where Y : BaseRepository<T>
{
 // Métodos de clase y demás.
}
```

Donde:

**IBaseService** es la interfaz de la que heredan todas mis clases tipo servicio

**T** es tipo **BaseAttributes**, clase que uso como entidad de base de datos en mi SQL context. Todas mis entidades la usan como base.

**Y** es tipo **BaseRepository**, clase que uso como base para todos mis Repositorios de acceso a datos SQL.

Ahora,tengo el siguiente repositorio, que como pueden ver, hereda del padre **BaseRepository**. SQLContext es el contexto de EntityFramework.:

```
public class UserRepository(SqlContext context) : BaseRepository<User>(context), IUserRepository
{
    //Métodos de clase y demás.
}
```

Lo que estoy intentando hacer, es que, en BaseService, tener una instancia de cualquier hijo de BaseRepository. En mi teoría, como mis demás repositorios heredan de base repository, podría hacer lo siguiente en el constructor de BaseService:

```
public BaseService(SqlContext context)
{
    Y Repository; // Y es un repositorio hijo de BaseRepository. En este ejemplo, digamos,es  de tipo UserRepository.
    BaseRepository<T> repository = new(context); // T es tipo User, que hereda de BaseAttributes.
    Repository = (Y)repository; //Casteo el repositorio BaseRepository, a UserRepository, pero consigo un invalidCastException.
    
}
```

El error específico es el siguiente:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
> 'Repositories.Implementations.BaseRepository`1[Entities.Models.Users.User]'
> to type 'Repositories.Implementations.UserRepository'.'

¿Esto es posible de hacer?, y si es así, ¿Qué no estoy teniendo en cuenta?
Agradecería su ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inicio con una pequeña critica: si bien tu pregunta está bien formulada carece de un ejemplo mínimo y verificable, el cual era perfectamente posible realizarlo. Yo tuve que crear todas las otras clases que te faltó mostrar y entender la telaraña de herencias que tienes para reproducir el problema.

Y tu problema ni siquiera está en ese enredo, si no que en algo mucho más básico, y es que intentas castear una clase "padre" en un "hijo" y eso no es posible de realizar, ya que por naturaleza el hijo cuenta con más características que el padre.

La solución a tu problema es instanciar el objeto usando la clase `Activator`, de esta manera:

```
public BaseService(SqlContext context)
{
    Y repository = (Y)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Y),new object[] {context});
}
```

---

Como nota adicional, para los caso donde debes crear una instancia de una clase cuyo constructor es sin parámetros puedes usar un `where T: new()`, por ejemplo: Supongamos que NO que el `SqlContext` no existe

Ahí sencillamente haces:

```
public class BaseService<T, Y> : IBaseService<T, Y> where T : BaseAttributes where Y : BaseRepository<T> , new()
{
    public BaseService(SqlContext context)
    {
        Y repository = new Y(); //Solo para cuando el tipo Y cuanta con un constructo sin argumentos
    }
}
```

Comment: una disculpa, creí que con lo que había mostrado era suficiente, y siendo honesto, no tenía mucha idea de cómo presentar mi pregunta, ya que me era complicada de formular en un principio, trataré de dar más contexto para la próxima vez

Comment: @L.Ronquillo O sea la explicación que diste era buena, tanto que pude reconstruir el asunto, pero habría facilitado la vida tener un [MCVE] listo para ejecutar, algo como esto https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1hu6.png

Comment: Por otro lado te sirvió la respuesta?

Comment: sí! no había tenido el tiempo de volver aquí para marcarla, pero fue justo lo que quería, muchas gracias, compañero :)